# How to explain near apocalyptic conditions?

Tags: science-fiction

Let's say we have an island about half the size of Madagascar. I need to create an eclipse lasting several days, with ocasional "rain of fire", maybe floods.

Is there a way that a celestial body could cause this? As in a comet flying by and the tail pieces raining down?

Comment: The moon destabilizing and crashing into the earth probably could explain such a long apocalypse and the floods, pieces of the broken moon could make the "rain of fire", although you'd have to explain how they got here faster than the actual moon, but this scenario would cause an actual, full apocalypse shortly thereafter (barring divine intervention) so I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Drastic artificial climate change, similar to around effect 1,000,000 of nuclear weapon, if this planet/island is not on earth, you can have the atmosphere of the permanently similar to rain of fire. Explosion of super volcano like one in yellow stone mountain, would also lead to months,years of eclipse and frequent rains of fire, flood can be because of uncertain tectonic actives and tsunami.

Comment: Wouldn't the volcano eruption, provided it was large enough to darken the entire island also cause some more permanent damage, similar to the moon crashing down?

Comment: Are you happy to have whatever causes these conditions affect most or all of the planet? Or do you need the effects to be (mostly) confined to this island? The latter is a lot harder.

Comment: it can affect the entire world, it can also cause permanent damage elsewhere, but I need this island to be able to still recover after about a week of darkness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could look to celestial bodies for such a thing. But you could look much closer to home. Chinu already touched on super volcanoes, but why does it have to be so epic? Let me paint two picture for you, both of which might well answer your question.

**First - The personal apocalypse.** In this scenario, you don't need the world to end, just the world of your protagonist, or whomever you're central point of view follows. In this case, just a typical (if somewhat extreme) volcanic eruption or earthquake can/will/may meet your criterion. For example, major earthquake near a string of active volcanoes. It could be argued that the earthquake (i.e. the sudden shift of a tectonic plate) forces a pocket of magma to be shot up through the already present 'channel(s)' to the volcano(es), causing said volcano(es) to erupt (https://www2.usgs.gov/faq/categories/9840/2554). There's your rain of fire, and eruptions can last for hours, days, weeks, or even years dependent on a number of factors (http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/how-long-do-eruptions-last). Then, if the earthquake does something bad, you get your flood in the form of a tsunami.

Now, this first route may or may not be the world ending apocalypse you seek, but they have ended cities, even civilizations. Though, it does have the potential to be as catastrophic as you desire. Personally, I see it more as a... well, personal apocalypse. That is to say, MY city, MY world is ending.

**The other - global apocalypse.** Let's take the moon crashing into the earth scenario? But really, this applies to any large body. The closer the large body gets to the planet, the more each body's gravity will malform the other. That could be one plausible explanation for the flood (gravity pulling on the water, creating flood tides). Or a much simpler one would be a large object hitting the moon first, alter its orbit and sending it hurdling into the earth (or perhaps just sending large chunks towards the earth in an armageddon-styled rain of death).

If you go with the celestial body route, I would advise you studying up on the plausibility of it. Don't go with a 'meteor shower raining down on earth', though. It's highly unlikely, because anything large enough to really create the damage your question implies, its gravity would likely cause it to 'absorb' other similar-(and most definitely smaller-)sized bodies. One plausible reasoning, could be that it (just like my previous 'moonstruck scenario') was first struck by another body, altering its course, and perhaps breaking it into smaller bits, for the 'rain of fire' you're looking for. Some bits might well arrive well before others, so that could stretch it out over the course of many days.

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: It would seem that the tectonic activity along with the volcanic eruptions is the way to go, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.